# Modify a sequence into a countable local base

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose that you were given a sequence $M_1, M_2, M_3, \ldots$ of neighborhoods of a point $p$ in a space $(X, \tau)$ such that for every neighborhood $N$ of $p, \ \exists n \in \mathbb N$ such that $M_n \subseteq N.$ How could you modify the given material to produce a countable local base at $p$?

Would the following work? Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

For every $N_i$ of $p$, there’s $n \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $n = i+ 1$ and $M_n \subseteq N_i$?

Or

for every $N$ of $p, \ \exists n \in \mathbb N$ such that $M_n \subseteq N \subseteq M_{n - 1}?$

Comment: The $M_n$ (or their interiors) are already a countable local bast at $p$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, do you mean there's no point to this problem? If so, I'd like to skip it immediately to save time.

Comment: Are neighbourhoods necessarily open in your definition ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, The following are the defns from my book. That of neighborhood: https://ibb.co/JmLG1hb and def. of countable local base: https://ibb.co/10bTp1Q

Comment: In those definitions you’re done. By definition.